# How to determine first and last days of the week from timestamps?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with following data:

```
trtime:2019-01-31 11:03:33.000 || tr_count:1
trtime:2019-01-31 11:23:33.000 || tr_count:2
trtime:2019-01-31 12:13:33.000 || tr_count:5
trtime:2019-01-31 12:43:33.000 || tr_count:1
```

And I want output in this format:

```
time_till:2019-01-31 12:00:00.000 || tr_count:3
time_till:2019-01-31 13:00:00.000 || tr_count:6
```

i.e consolidate at every hour.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `casting` with `grouping` to convert the types as the query below

```
with tab(trtime,tr_count) as
(
select convert(varchar, '2019-01-31 11:03:33.000', 120),1 union all
select convert(varchar, '2019-01-31 11:23:33.000', 120),2 union all
select convert(varchar, '2019-01-31 12:13:33.000', 120),5 union all
select convert(varchar, '2019-01-31 12:43:33.000', 120),1 
)    
select cast(cast(trtime as date) as varchar) +' '
      +cast(1+datepart(hour,trtime) as varchar) + ':00:00.000'
       as time_till,
       sum(tr_count) as tr_count
  from tab
 group by cast(cast(trtime as date) as varchar) +' '
         +cast(1+datepart(hour,trtime ) as varchar) + ':00:00.000' 

time_till                tr_count
-----------------------  --------
2019-01-31 12:00:00.000     3
2019-01-31 13:00:00.000     6
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/XIZWT83338)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH TempResult as
(select CONVERT(date, time) myDate, DATEPART(HOUR, time)+1 myHour,count(id) tr_count
from myTable
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, time), DATEPART(HOUR, time))
Select DATEADD(hour,myHour+1,Convert(Datetime, myDate)) time_till,tr_count   from TempResult
```

Comment: thanks for your help, can you plz rewrite your query? The time column is confusing hence I changed it to trtime